# Azure CosmosDb parameterized query throws "Invalid query. Specified parameterized query JSON is malformed."

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I try to send a simple query to a CosmosDb database using the code below. However it throws the exception *"Invalid query. Specified parameterized query JSON is malformed."*

```
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM products p where p.label = @Token")
                .WithParameter("@Token", "a_string");

var results = new List<ProductDocument>();
using (FeedIterator<ProductDocument> resultSetIterator = Container.GetItemQueryIterator<ProductDocument>(query))
{
    while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<ProductDocument> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        results.AddRange(response);
    }
}
```

I tried different variations, sending the partition key in the options, but I keep getting the same exception.
I also have other methods where I use Linq to SQL to query cosmosdb and it works so my container is well instantiated.

I am using the Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK V3.

Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Get rid of the "products" in your query text.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried without the "products" but I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Misspelled label by chance? Capital L? Sorry, i can't see anything else wrong here.